# Matomo tracking API not tracking

Tags: c#, .net, matomo

I'm trying to integrate Matomo Tracking Api with a Windows Universal App as there are no packages that work for this framework.

Currently I'm building the URL by myself and making a `POST` call to the server like this:

`https://mycompanyname.matomo.cloud/matomo.php?action_name=My+Custom+Event&idsite=1234&rand=6265608&rec=1&apiv=1&cookie=1&apiv=1`

This is constantly sending a `400` with a pixel inside. Any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally I'm trying to solve an issue on Android but I'm managing to send requests - it's just that somehow they are not tracked so I hope the following information will help you.

I think your main issue is that you are trying to send a `POST` request. As I understand it the `POST` request is only supported when using [Bulk Tracking](https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/tracking-api#bulk-tracking). In your case you should be using a `GET` request, as a quick example you can have a look at this sample [here](https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/tracking-api#example-tracking-request).

One suggestion from my end: set `send_image` as `send_image=0` in your query string so that a GIF is not returned. (Documented [here](https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/tracking-api#other-parameters)).

Comment: Thanks will give it a try, wish their support was as good as your answer.

Comment: You're welcome, in the end I solved my issue - not sure if it will apply to you, but in my case I had to make sure to send a correct URL to track. The URL host needs to be the same as the URLs you set for your Matomo Site settings. Example if you are tracking abc.com, your request should track abc.com/whatever/you/want. I found that out by switching on the debugger (https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/tracking-api#debugging-the-tracker) - it might help you too.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that we are using Matomo not to track a Webpage but to track events from a mobile app, and thus it doesn't have anything to do with the website scenario. The .net package they have is unusable as it is 6 years old, that is why I was trying to make it work with custom http calls, but seems difficult. Their support also is not very helpful.

Comment: My scenario was in a mobile app as well. The Matomo project I'm linking to is a website not a mobile app. Not sure how much of a difference that will make, because at the end of the day the GET request will be the same. In my case I had an issue because the page URL I was passing didn't match with the site URL of the Matomo project.

Comment: My guess is that your Matomo project is for a mobile app? Checkout this example they have https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/tracking-api#example-tracking-request as mentioned it's a simple GET request so you can do it yourself rather than using any SDK.

If your mobile app is a native app you can use their SDKs too: https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo-sdk-android & https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo-sdk-ios.

I opted "manual" tracking as it's a NativeScript mobile app and it was easier to integrate it like so.